# Engine Vibration 2007 Honda Accord

Tags: engine, troubleshooting, vibration

2007 Honda Accord vibrates really bad when put in drive or reverse, but when in park it doesn't.  Even turning the AC on makes the vibration/noise worse. Any advice?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is the check engine light on? If so, have you read the codes? If you haven't, get them read and please let us know what they are. At a guess, I'd suggest you might have a bad coil/plug/injector on one cylinder, but that's a guess ... you really don't give us much to go on here.

Answer (score 1):

This is a hard one with what little information there is to go on. Sounds like a misfire but usually (especially with a 4 cylinder engine) you would feel it at idle in park if it was a totally dead cylinder. First thing I would do is unplug the coils, crank the engine over for a few seconds and listen to it, I’ve seen plenty of these Hondas partially loose compression on a cylinder due to timing issues and with a good ear you’ll hear it clear as day when cranking it, it’ll sound consistent for the most part but you’ll get a random jump is crank speed for every revolution, it’s hard to explain over text but I hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this problem on many cars.  Clean the throttle body shutter with throttle body cleaner and a toothbrush.  With the engine running and the a/c on, spray throttle body cleaner through the port just in front of the throttle body shutter, in short spurts, for five minutes.  Replace the air filter.

Change the crankcase oil, substituting one quart with Marvel Mystery Oil.  (@Paulster2 - there is nothing in the Terms and Conditions of this forum that disallow product names, so stop reprimanding me.)

Put cleaners in the gas tank.  On 7/8 of a tank, add 32 oz. Marvel Mystery Oil, 32 oz. Liqui-Moly Fuel Injector cleaner, and two gallons of lacquer thinner.  Rev the engine in neutral at stop lights with quick pumps to the floor.  On an open highway, floor the pedal on a hot day, 50 - 80 MPH, at least five times.  Do not refill the tank until very near empty.

Change the oil again after 300 miles.  You may have to continue adding a few ounces of MMO and change the oil every 1000 miles if your crankcase is particularly dirty.

If the problem persists, change the oil and add [Restore](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00HJVEWVG) to the crankcase.  This step will correct the loss of compression discussed by DieselMech.